# Delete ALL Assemblies from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Question is pretty simple but just in case I'll explain it.

Is there a way to drop ALL the the assemblies in a Microsoft SQL Server?

I know that there's a way to delete them on at a time using

```
DROP ASSEMBLY ['assembly_name'];
```

Comment: Nope, will have to cycle through available ones and go one by one.

Comment: Thanks! But in that case, is there a way to list them? Cause I'm working in a legacy DB.

Comment: Try the system table `sys.assemblies`, I think it's available from version 2008 onwards. This table is scoped by database tho.

Comment: Thanks! That one worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with assemblies but they should be in a structure within sys like everything else on SQL SERVER. I usually build massive commands by using a code similar to this one. 
Please note that within my environment all the tables related to assemblies are empty so I cannot say if the table and column I picked up with the select are correct, you will need to figure out on yourself.

```
declare @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @cmd=''
select 
@cmd=@cmd+ 'DROP ASSEMBLY [''' + am.assembly_class +'''];'+CHAR(13)
 from sys.assembly_modules am

 PRINT @cmd

 --Copy and paste the Messages content from SQL Server Management studio to a new query or uncomment the row below to execute
 --EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: this code does not allow for dependencies between assemblies,
so you may have to run it 2-3 times before all assemblies are dropped.

```
/* Drop all assemblies */
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.assemblies WHERE is_user_defined=1
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP ASSEMBLY ' + RTRIM(@name)
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```